# How I extract the x-csrf-token in request header and pass to post https request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I can't extract the x-csrf-token and pass . I got error like csrf token expired [![enter image description here][image: enter image description hereenter image description here]

Anyone give some exact ans and support.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't contain sufficient level of details so it cannot be answered comprehensively.

1. First of all check your `${x}` JMeter Variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination
2. Then check the request header using the aforementioned View Results Tree listener. The token should be exactly the same as the one returned in the previous request.

Also it seems that your token comes in JSON-like structure, [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) so it would be a better idea considering using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of Regular Expression Extractor